# Dynamically reference a sheet name in a SUM formula

Tags: google-sheets, sum

I have 28 different tabs representing weekly data. They are titled W1, W2, W3 .... all the way up to W28. They are identically laid out just different data.

On a separate tab I am trying to SUM some fields from each week.

That tab will look like so

```
Week - Wins
1    - 4
2    - 2
3    - 3
```

the static formula for the first row in the win column would be:
=SUM('W1'!AW2:AW7)

But I want to make it dynamically reference the sheet name. Let's assume Week # is column C and they start in row 4. This formula seems to return the proper sheet names:

="'W"&INDIRECT("C4:C31")&"'" (Gives me 'W1', 'W2', 'W3', etc in the corresponding wins column)

But I am unable to combine it with the above SUM formula to dynamically reference the sheet name.

=SUM("'W"&INDIRECT("C4:C31")&"'"&!AW2:AW7) -> Formula Parse Error
=SUM('W&INDIRECT("C4:C31")&'!AW2:AW7) -> Unresolved Sheet Name W&INDIRECT("C4:C31")&

I've tried other variations with no luck so far.

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 1):

example:

[image]

[image]

formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(REDUCE(, SEQUENCE(28), LAMBDA(a, b, {a; IFERROR(IMPORTRANGE(
 "1ToGglifTsqotZ0jDthW2rojWbIXRYPvKUHpdJVzpZ_I", "W"&b&"!B2:B5"))})))
```

[image]

or:

```
=SUM(REDUCE(, SEQUENCE(28), LAMBDA(a, b, 
 {a; IFERROR(INDIRECT("W"&b&"!B2:B5"))})))
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
=QUERY(REDUCE(, SEQUENCE(28), LAMBDA(a, b, 
 {a; SUM(IFERROR(INDIRECT("W"&b&"!B2:B5")))})), "offset 1", )
```

[image]

Comment: That looks like it totals all sheets together. I want each weeks row to title that weeks sheet's range. So the summary she would list total wins per week.

Comment: so above example would have a third page that had 2 columns, Week #s and corresponding SUM totals (1,2 with 9,6) Sorry not sure how to format comments to better show that visually

Comment: but I'll take a look at SEQUENCE, REDUCE and LAMBDA and see how they work. Thx

Comment: Your update worked perfectly. Thank you so very much. I appreciate your time and knowledge.