# I want to get the matrices with reference in the cells

Tags: google-sheets

The formula works when I type manually, but when I try to get the references of the tabs inside the cells it doesn't work, can someone help me?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KVyLhBRamHyjq_DD92X78OfBvzh0bUDTnf_WTojTnpg/edit#gid=2097694625

[image]

I tried to put it like this, but it didn't work.

[image]

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=QUERY({REDUCE({"","","","","","","","",""}, 
 FILTER(L5:L, L5:L<>""), LAMBDA(a, b, 
 {a; IFERROR(INDIRECT(b&"!G1:O"), {"","","","","","","","",""})}))}, 
 "where not Col8 is null", )
```

where L5:L is your:

[image]

see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74483215/5632629

---

### UPDATE:

```
=QUERY({REDUCE({""\""\""\""\""\""\""\""\""}; 
 FILTER(SHEETSNAME(); REGEXMATCH(SHEETSNAME(); "sin")); LAMBDA(a; b; 
 {a; IFERROR(INDIRECT(b&"!G1:O"); {""\""\""\""\""\""\""\""\""})}))}; 
 "where not Col8 is null"; )
```

[image]

Comment: The information given in that formula you put was "analysis error"

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KVyLhBRamHyjq_DD92X78OfBvzh0bUDTnf_WTojTnpg/edit#gid=2097694625

Comment: @SauloMoté sheet is private

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KVyLhBRamHyjq_DD92X78OfBvzh0bUDTnf_WTojTnpg/edit