# Google Sheets: iterate through a list of keywords in a filter formula

Tags: loops, google-sheets-formula, filtering

I have a list of keywords (each in separate cell), for example:

| Keyword A | (cell C1)
| Keyword B | (cell C2)
| Keyword C | (cell C3)

and I have a formula that searches for these keywords across different worksheets and returns the sum of values corresponding to a given keyword:

```
=SUM(FILTER(INDIRECT("'"& B6 & "'!G1:G600");INDIRECT("'" & B6 & "'!B1:B600")=A6))
```

where A6 contains an in-cell dropdown list of these keywords to choose from and B6 contains an in-cell dropdown list of worksheets to work in (let's say for different months).

Example: When 'Keyword A' is found in worksheet 'January' in column B, find the corresponding value to this keyword in column G; then ultimately sum all of these values for a given worksheet and a given keyword.

Depending on what I choose from the in-cell dropdown list, I get the corresponding sum for a given keyword. However, I'd like to get the total sum of all the keyword values added together, but I can`t seem to make it work. Feels like I'd have to use some equivalent of a for loop to iterate through the list and add up the individual sums, but as far as I'm concerned, there's no looping possible in Google Sheets.

I can, obviously, define these sums for each keyword separately and then add these values together, but as I'm working with large datasets with many keywords, this solution is rather unpleasant.

All suggestions are much appreciated!

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: here's a sample of my sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bbwVPpXqsu-FBg8xHRTCGLFkCl7sxKdtoielZ1IuLMA/edit?usp=sharing with the desired output highlighted in red.

Answer (score 0):

try REDUCE:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(REDUCE({""\""}; H4:INDEX(H:H; MAX(ROW(H:H)*(H:H<>""))); LAMBDA(a; b; 
 {a; IFERROR(INDIRECT(b&"!B4:C"); {""\""})})); 
 "select sum(Col2) where Col1 matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|"; 1; I4:I)&"'"); 2)
```

[image]

see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74483215/5632629

---

### update:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(REDUCE({""\""\""}; H4:INDEX(H:H; MAX(ROW(H:H)*(H:H<>""))); LAMBDA(a; b; 
 {a; {IFERROR(INDIRECT(b&"!B4:C"); {""\""\""})\b&IFERROR(A4:A/0)}})); 
 "select Col3,sum(Col2) where Col1 matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|"; 1; I4:I)&"' 
  group by Col3 label sum(Col2)''"))
```

[image]

Comment: A bit hard for me to understand at first glance, could you explain the formula a bit? Also, would it be possible to only get the result for a given month (the result then being either 19 or 20)? But otherwise great work, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Building on player0's answer, this formula, though a bit simplified, seems to be working just fine (taking a list and looking for members in a given spreadsheet to include in the sum), using Reduce and Query:

```
    =REDUCE(0; QUERY(INDIRECT("'"& B6 & "'!B7:G600");
     "select C where B matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|"; 1; L4:L)&"'"); 
     LAMBDA(x;total;total+x))
```