# Formula that fill a sheet if the data from another are being populated based on a criteria

Tags: google-sheets, import, formula

I'm going to be as clear as possible.

First of all I have 2 sheets:

Sheet 1: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AXPQyw_yZUfafjWNW82Rf9E02qR_0c_SYeKOnqQUUdE/edit?usp=sharing
Sheet 2:https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1v_AyqHXJVhzRNbL-yGoMLxnuKC3z67tZOcQAWwduCN0/edit?usp=sharing

Thank you for your help,

I'm feeling data in Sheet 1 for each week. In the example, I have week 49 and 50.

In Sheet 2, I have a tab for each week. I'd like to have a formula that based on the week number either from the tab name or from the cell A2 in my example, the formula check Sheet 1, look if there is some entries for the week in question and fill automatically the proper tab for the week.

Comment: The files are shared as `View only`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
`=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("url";"Sheet1A1:E");"select * where Col1 matches '"&A2&"'");`

I haven't tested it because the files are shared as `View`and I think that it at least puts you in the right direction.

**References**

- [IMPORTRANGE()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en)
- [QUERY()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=QUERY(REDUCE({""\""\""\""}; SEQUENCE(2; 1; 49); LAMBDA(y; x; {y; 
 IFERROR(IMPORTRANGE("1v_AyqHXJVhzRNbL-yGoMLxnuKC3z67tZOcQAWwduCN0"; 
 x&"!A3:D100"); {""\""\""\""})})); "where Col1 is not null"; )
```

[image]

see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74280310/5632629

and: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74483215/5632629